# PHP/HTML/MySQL Database Query with multi search parameters and display results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mysql

I am building a custom part builder form using html and all the items are on MySQL. On the form there are multiple dropdowns and buttons and one text input box. I want to know how do you connect the form to query the MySQL Database and then display the item on the page in a box.I want to display the query results in a box under the form.

Comment: Ajax?  Are you trying to send the information from the form to your MySQL database?

Comment: Try to use AJAX, and then write the result to the HTML DOM by using `document.getElementById('yourID').innerHTML = ...;`. Your box then would be a `<div id='yourID'>` with the ID specified in JavaScript.

Comment: So a customer fill out the form and then the part number and price are displayed

Comment: Then try using AJAX. It can communicate with a PHP file on your server which then can query a MySQL request.

Comment: Okay i'm new at this so it might take a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using AJAX, you can communicate with a PHP file on your server. This can then make MySQL queries and echo out the data you want to receive from the database.
Using JavaScript, you can then format this returned value and change the `innerHTML` of your *box* `<div>`.

**HTML**

```
<form>... Your form ...</form>
<div id="yourDiv"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "LINK_TO_YOUR_PHP_FILE.php",
    type: "post",
    data: YOUR_PARAM_DATA_FROM_HTML_FORM
});

request.done(function (response) {
    // Do something with the response...
    document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML = response;
});
```

**PHP**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "DB_USERNAME", "DB_PASSWORD", "DB_NAME");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ...";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo $row;
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: add Jquery at the bottom of the body element. Do NOT use Jquery SLIM version.

```
   <script src="/script/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Step 2: Make sure your data is wrapped in the form element and there is a button present in the form.

```
<form>
<input name="stuff" value="">
<button></button
</form>
```

Step 3: gather the information and send it to a php file with ajax.

```
$("form").submit(function(event){

            event.preventDefault(); 

alert("click");

        var data = $("form").serialize(); 

                $.ajax({
                type:'POST',

                url:'yourphppage.php',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() { 

                    alert(data);        

                },
                success:function(msg){

                    alert(msg);


                    if (!$.trim(msg)){   

                                alert("no message");

                    }else if($.trim(msg) == '1'){

                            alert("logged in");
                            //window.location.href = "/index.php";

                    }else if($.trim(msg) == '0'){

                            alert("email taken");

                    }else{

                        alert("error");
                    }

                    }

            }); 
    });
```

*the serialize data will grab the names of the input element and assign the values. then it makes a string of data to send.  like 'stuff=inputevalue?morestuff=inputvalue'.

Step 4: Create a php file that receives the data, stores data in your database and sends you a response.

Here is an example of a log in page,  It needs a post or die clause, but for testing this one is easy and shows lots of examples of how to test stuff.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    session_start();

require("db_connect.php");



    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.


        $email = stripslashes($_POST['stuff']); // removes backslashes

        // $email = stripslashes('aaron@treaze.com');

        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email); //escapes special characters in a string

        $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);

        // $password = stripslashes("hackme69");

        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);

        //echo $password."<br><br>";

        //echo $email."<br><br>";


        //Checking is user existing in the database or not

       // $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='$email'";
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='%s'", $email);

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysql_error());


        if($result){ 

            while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){

            $existingHashFromDb = $obj->password;
            $role = $obj->role;

        }

    if(password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb)){

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['role'] = $role;

        echo "1";


    }else{


        echo "0";

    }



}else{



    echo "No input";


     } 




?>
```

Step 5: make sure your database connection is in the same file directory and would look like this.

```
<?php

/* Database connection start */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "******";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "********";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


?>
```

Last step:  Set up a database to receive the values.

In conclusion, there are all examples of what to do. It gives you the concept. However, if this is new to you. My suggestion is to start very small and basic, then build up. Once you grasp the concept, you will be ajaxing everything around like a pro.

I also want to add... there a lot of ways to ajax. If you want to receive multiple responses from one one ajax call, you will need to learn how to convert the info to JSON and store the results in a variable Array.    Then you can access multiple responses.

This is an example of the PHP code for getting multiple values and sending them in one response.

```
<?php

session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');


include_once("db_connect.php");


$getusername = $_GET["username"];

$getusername = $_SESSION['username'];



$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users4 WHERE username= '".$getusername."' ");

if($results){ 

while($obj = $results->fetch_object())

{
$username=$obj->username;
$firstName=$obj->name;  
$lastName=$obj->lastName;
$email=$obj->email;
$dob=$obj->dob;
}

}


echo json_encode(array("firstName" => $firstName, "lastName" => $lastName, "email" => $email, "dob" => $dob, "username" => $getusername));


?>
```

This is a AJAX example with JSON.

```
  function initiateCall() {
    //  alert("sending text to" + $("#phone_number").val() );

    $.post("call.php", { phone_number : $("#phoneNumber").val() }, 
      function(data) { showCodeForm(data.verification_code); }, "json");




  }
```

You have to figure out whats best for you. I hope this gives you some direction.